# When will $f(x)=c$ separate the space into two parts ($f(x)>c$ and $f(x)<c$)?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

When will $f(x)=c$ separating the space into two parts ($f(x)>c$ and $f(x)<c$)? Here $x$ is a vector.

Let me clarify what I mean by "separating". I want $f(x)=c$ to be a continuous boundary such that $f(x)>c$ and $f(x)<c$ are on each side of it. I don't know the exact definition of "side" in mathematics, but I feel that the way $\mathbb{R}^2$ is separated as inside and outside by $x^2+y^2=1$ does not count.

Is there any other condition in addition to $f$ being linear? My guess is that $f(x)$ being monotonic (and continuous) is a sufficient condition. For example, if $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing in both $x$ and $y$, then $f(x)>c$ will be to the northeast of $f(x)=c$ and $f(x)<c$ will be to the southwest of $f(x)=c$.

I really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: If $x$ is a vector, why do you talk about $f(x,y)$? You want $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) < c\}$ and $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) > c\}$ unbounded, right? What do you think about a function that splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that one partition is $\{(0,t) \mid t >0\}$?

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistent notation. I mean the x in f(x) is a vector. But when I wrote f(x,y), I meant to emphasize it is two-dimension. I have to admit I don't have a clear picture in my mind. My initial observation is that when f is linear, it is the case where a hyperplane separates the space into two parts. Then I was thinking what if the boundary is curvy rather than flat.  So I guess maybe a more precise description should be that f(x)=c is a hypersurface? In this sense, I think the example your proposed does not fall into this type?

Comment: So you want conditions on $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for some $c>0$ we have that $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is a surface bounding a simply connected region? I think this is a non-trivial question, but I am also not an expert geometer or topologist. My guess is that there is a result to this end.

Comment: Maybe even "for all c" rather than "for some c"?

Comment: This should be the Hahn-Banach separation theorem which can be found as a reference in Brezis, Functional Analysis.

Comment: I checked wiki, and I feel that the theorem is about separating two convex sets with a hyperplane. But my initial idea is to consider hypersurface rather than hyperplane. So I think the theorem may be relevant but does not explicitly answer my question.

Comment: @Ypbor I understand by your meaning of "side" that you want both "sides" to be unbounded, is that right? Because for example, the inside of a circle is a bounded set, but if I consider a hyperplane, both sides of it are unbounded. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe also connected?

Comment: Yes, of course, connected as well. To make things extremely precise : you want a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\{f(x)>c\}$ and $\{f(x)<c\}$ are disjoint, unbounded, connected sets, with the boundaries of each set equalling $\{f(x) = c\}$. This is a question in topology, but let us first work out some simple conditions if possible.

Comment: I think it should be R^n->R. By the way, how can I type TeX as you did?

Comment: @Ypbor Wrap your code along \$ signs . For example, `$R^n \to R$` produces $R^n \to R$. But I'm concerned about one thing : you want an $f$ so that for *all* $c$, the above property occurs, right? (That is , for *all* $c$), you want the conditions I mentioned to occur, right?

Comment: When $f$ is linear, it is true for all $c$, right? So I think a natural extension of it should also apply for all $c$.

Comment: Correct, absolutely right! Let me see if I can be of service to you, thank you for the further elaboration, please take my +1 with you.

Comment: I should be thanking you : )

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi, have you made any progress on this?

Comment: @Ypbor Indeed , I have made a lot of progress, and thought a lot about a good , streamlined answer. But I'm in the process of doing a lot of things at once, including non-MSE things, so I'm literally having to save progress using external resources and what not. I'll definitely give you a result soon, perhaps the weekend is a good time to finish typing up the answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you so much for your effort. Take your time. I wish all the things you are doing go well!